# Why is my jquery data not displaying in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and this has me so confused. I didn't write this code but I need it to work, of course!
The problem is the information does not display in my  `<p>` tag. Everything seems to work until I get to `var hint_result`. But I just don't know why the information is not displaying. Trying to love javascript but struggling :)
It should display the password hint.
This is an exmaple of what is sent back :

```
{"CONDITION":"true","MESSAGE":"top of the fruit","UUID":"1851-CCC6-A8A80A1B148637C6"}
```

Code :

```
<!--- Password Hint Window Start --->
<div class="password_hint">
  <p>Forgot your password?<br />No problem... we can fix that!</p>

<div class="hint_form">
  <p>Enter your email address</p>
    <form method="post">
      <input placeholder="Email_address" name="password_hint_email_address" type="text" tabindex="1" />
  <p class="button small passwordHint" style="width: 100%; margin: 1px 0 10px;" tabindex="2" >Submit</p>
</form>
</div>

                <!--- Error Messages --->
                <p class="hint_result"></p>
            </div>


(function() {               
$("p.button.small.passwordHint").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: globalURL+"/myfolder/userlogin.cfc?" + url_params,
      data: { 
        method: "PasswordHint",
        email: $("input[name='password_hint_email_address']").val()
      },
      success: function(hint) {
        var hint = jQuery.parseJSON(hint);

            if (hint.CONDITION == true) {
      var hint_result = $("p.hint_result").html("Your password hint is \"" + hint.MESSAGE + "\"").addClass(" messageSuccess");
      $(hint_result).show("slow");
    } else if (hint.CONDITION == false) {
        var hint_result = $("p.hint_result").html(hint.MESSAGE).addClass(" messageError");
        $(hint_result).show("slow");
    } 
      },
      error: function(e) {
        // handle error
        //alert("Sorry there has been an error");
      }
    });
});
}());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check ajax starting using F12 Development Tool on click

Comment: $(hint_result) > you don't need to place this in $(). hint_result is already a JQuery object. Not sure if this will resolve your problem because I don't understand what is going wrong/unexpected from your question.

Comment: I concur @Reinard.  I think that's the issue (one of them at anyway).  Didn't see your comment when I was posting my answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delaying in getting back to you - weekend- . I have made the change to the code but still the text does not appear. I've checked the console. No errors. I added  'console.log(hint_result);' just after the 'var hint_result' but even this does not display in the console. Not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I  figured out where the issue is. My 'if statement is not working'. I don't understand why because my condition is 'true'. If I remove the statement, the code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code `<script>` You should try to this tag's in put your code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with this line:

```
$(hint_result).show("slow");
```

The line before it sets hint_result to a jQuery object ([addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) returns a jQuery object):

```
var hint_result = $("p.hint_result").html("Your password hint is \"" + hint.MESSAGE + "\"").addClass(" messageSuccess");
```

So, you can simply remove the selector syntax around hint_result.  Your fixed line would look like this:

```
hint_result.show("slow");
```

The selector syntax $("...") actually creates a jQuery object from a DOM element(s), but hint_result is already a jQuery object.